# facebook plugins not refreshing together

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, refresh

i have two **Facebook plugins**(like and comment box) on my page.
when i login with on plugin it not logins another plugin automatically until i refresh page.

for example : when i login by  clicking on like button,my *comment box* remains in logout state until i refresh page.

please suggest me something good for that problem

my code is as follow

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {



FB.init({ appId: 'My app ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });


        FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.render", function (targetUrl) {
            $("#myh1").html("Facebook Loaded");
            //alert('edge.create');
            setTimeout(aaa, 500);



        });

        FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading(function () {
            alert("Done loading");
        });



        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function (response) {
            alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());


    function aaa() {

        $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollButtons: {
                enable: false
            }
        });
    }

</script>


<div class="fb-like" data-send="false"  data-href="http://www.facebook.com    /AiLiveCaptions"   data-width="298" data-show-faces="true">
        </div>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/AiLiveCaptions" data-num-    posts="8" order_by="reverse_time" data-width="280"></div>
```

Comment: Make it refresh the page automatically at the end?

Comment: i don't want to  refresh whole the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

to render XFBML markup in a document on the fly.

[**FB Documentation**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)